# Identity field in a Composite Key using FluentNHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, identity, composite-key

I have a table with a composite key, one part of which is an Identity field. The Identity field was obviously added later, because there are over 1000 places where the identity is duplicated, thus relying on the second part of the composite key to provide uniqueness. Here is the table declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblSaveCommissions](
    [SaveTransID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CommID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [AccountNumber] [varchar](40) NULL,
    ... (extra fields)
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblSaveCommissions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SaveTransID] ASC,
    [CommID] ASC)
)
```

The FluentNHibernate mapping looks like this (abbreviated):

```
public class SaveCommissionMap : ClassMap<SaveCommissionEntity>
{
    public SaveCommissionMap()
    {
        Table("tblSaveCommissions");

        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "CommID")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.SaveTransactionId, "SaveTransId");

        Map(x => x.AccountNumber);

        References(x => x.SaveTransaction)
            .Column("SaveTransId").Not.Insert().Not.Update();
    }
```

Now when I try to insert a record, I get the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tblSaveCommissions' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

How can I work the mapping to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

some alternate possibility is to make `SaveCommission` a dependant component of SaveTransaction.

```
class SaveTransaction
{
    public virtual IList<SaveCommission> Commissions { get; set; }
}

class SaveTransactionMap : ClassMap<SaveTransaction>
{
    public SaveTransactionMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Commissions)
            .KeyColumn("SaveTransID")
            .AsBag()
            .OrderBy("CommID")
            .Component(c => 
            {
                c.ParentReference(x => x.SaveTransaction);
                c.Map(x => x.AccountNumber);
            })
    }
}
```